# Why Elasticsearch and Kibana are required to set up Filebeat?

Tags: filebeat, elk

I'm new to Filebeat, and reading through the official setup guide.
Link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-installation-configuration.html

I don't understand why ES and Kibana are required, if I want the filebeat output sent to console or another file?